# Javascript only on scroll events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, onscroll

Is it possible to create a minimalist javasript only on-scroll function to hide my menu bar, so only the menu button shows and the button itself gains a white backgroud colour? I have been looking into this and I believed to have the code fairly down. But I am very new to javasript and cannot fully understand the syntax of it yet. Below is what I have now in a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/AngusBerry/zLt0yLou/2/#&togetherjs=Vsth32pa6L

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1><span id="tstscroll">0</span></h1>
    <div class="MenuButton" id="mobMenu"></div>
    <!--<p>as you can see, this is the header for the website. Here will also be contained all of the links to anywhere on the support system. this and the footer will both be FIXED and will move with the page.</p>-->
  </header>
</body>
```

css:

```
  header {
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 3.5px;
  color: green;
  animation: max-height-header;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

header .MenuButton {
  width: 28px;
  height: 6px;
  border-top: 6px solid;
  border-bottom: 18px double;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

javascript:

```
var mobilemenu = document.getElementById('mobMenu');
var testscroller = document.getElementById('tstscroll');
var x = 0;

document.mobilemenu.addEventListener("scroll", menuScrolMob);


function menuScrolMob(mobilemenu.onscroll) {
  testscroller.innerhtml = x += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to run that script either last in your body, or after page been loaded, or else it won't be able to access the elements.

Also, your script code is wrong, so here is a solution showing how to solve both those issues

```
(function(w, d) {        /* this is a closure and will keep its variables
                            from polluting the global namespace and it also
                            declare 2 variables (w, d) to be used inside it */

  w.addEventListener("load", function() {

    var mobilemenu = d.getElementById('mobMenu');
    var testscroller = d.getElementById('tstscroll');
    var x = 0;

    mobilemenu.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      testscroller.innerhtml = x += 1;    
    });

  });

}(window, document));    /* here I pass the window and document object into the
                            closure's variables (w, d) to make the code slimmer  */
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. You've said there that you declare 2 variables when opening the function, but where do you define the variables?

Edit - Sorry, only just interpreted the last comment meaning DX still very new to javascript. so would it be possibly to use 'w' and 'd' in the closure instance as well for this code?

Comment: @GusB They are defined as parameters `w` and `d` in the `(function(w, d) {..})`

Comment: @GusB As you can see I do that i.e. `d.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementById`

Comment: Okay.... nice! so i just need to make sure that this is beneath the html then? is it okay to reference the script sheet after html, or will the whole function need to be within script tags after the element i want it to link to...?

Comment: @GusB The above code can be either in the `<head>` tag or in the `<body>`, but wrapped in a `<script>` tag. This line in the code, `w.addEventListener("load", function() {...});` ensures that where ever you put it, it will not run until page been loaded, which the event listener name `load` imply

Comment: Thank you very muh for the input, it has been of gret help to me. the last thing that i would ask is: Now that ive looked back on my previous statement ive realised that i may have asked this question slightly incorrect as well, in the JS that you have written here, the function seems to act on a sroll event attached to the 'mobilemenu' var that was made, if i wanted this to occur when the page itself is scrolled, should i simply change the mobilemenu bit to window or document?
this here to w or d?--> mobilemenu.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

Comment: @GusB You should attach it to the `window` and can use `w.addEventListener("scroll", function() {...});` as I did with the `load` listener. `w` is a variable reference to `window` in this case, and works in the same way.

Comment: Awsome, thank you very much... i believe this has helped my understanding of JS a little more, it shall not be forgotten :)